# Binomial Processes to find probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, binomial-distribution, stationary-processes

Consider a series of independent coin shots with the possibility of $p$ coming head in any shot. Let $Y_n$ be the numbers of heads in first $n$ consecutive shots of the coin. In this case find the probability of $\left \{ Y_{5}=3,Y_{8}=5,Y_{14}=9 \right \}$.

$\left \{ Y_{n},n=1,2,3,... \right \}$ is a Binomial process.

$Y_{8}-Y_{5}=Z_{6}+Z_{7}+Z_{8}=2$

$Y_{14}-Y_{8}=Z_{9}+Z_{10}+Z_{11}+...+Z_{14}=4$ then from here

$Y_{14}-Y_{5}=6$

$\Rightarrow P(\left \{ Y_{14}-Y_{5}=6\right \})=P(Y_{9}=6)=\binom{9}{6}p^{6}q^{3}$

But the right answer is $450p^{9}q^{5}$

Where did I go wrong? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Event $\{Y_5=3,Y_8=5,Y_{14}=9\}\subset\{Y_{14}-Y_5=6\}$ but the events are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$$Y_5=3\text{ and }Y_8=5\text{ and }Y_{14}=9\iff Y_5=3\text{ and }Y_8-Y_5=2\text{ and }Y_{14}-Y_8=4$$

So you should go for finding: $$P(Y_5=3,Y_8-Y_5=2,Y_{14}-Y_8=4)$$ where the rv's $Y_5$ ,$Y_8-Y_5$, $Y_{14}-Y_8$ are independent.

Comment: Why we find like this?

Comment: 1) Do you agree with the equivalence? 2) Do you agree that the mentioned rv's are independent (so that we can find the probability as product of separate probabilities)?

Comment: @softglance Because $P( Y_{5}=3,Y_{8}=5,Y_{14}=9) $ $= P( Y_{14}=9 \mid Y_{5}=3,Y_{8}=5)P( Y_{8}=5 \mid Y_{5}=3)P(Y_{5}=3)$ $=P( Y_{14}-Y_{8}=4)P( Y_{8}- Y_{5}=2)P(Y_{5}=3)$ and you can calculate that

Comment: Thanks for both of you